# tkinter validation for file directory

Tags: python, tkinter

For my program, there is an input for username and file name. The program then goes into their shared folder and retrieves the file. I want to error proof this step by returning a dialog box if the file directory does not exist.

Would the error exception step go before or after my mainloop()? How would I go about doing it?

Comment: It will be done _in_ the main loop. You need to read up on the basics of gui programming and events.

Comment: "The program then goes..." When does it do this? Right as the window opens? After the user enters an individual character into the username field? When the user clicks a "submit" button? Something else?

Comment: Generally speaking, no GUI code should be after the call to `mainloop`.

Comment: The error step would go in the function that opens the share folder. You could write it as a `Try/Except` statement that runs the except section if try fails for any reason.